# How to set an object null if all of its fields are null?

Tags: json, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

How to set an object null if all of its fields are null?

**De-serializing**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
DetailUser detailUser = gson.fromJson(json, DetailUser.class);
```

**DetailUser** where disconnect should be null if all of its fields are null

```
public class DetailUser {
    String email;
    Integer age;
    Disconnect disconnect;
}
```

**Disconnect**

```
public class Disconnect {
    String text;
    String beginning;
    String end;
}
```

**JSON** by which `disconnect` should be null

```
{
    "email":"test@test.test",
    "age":33,
    "disconnect":{}
}
```

**JSON** by which `disconnect` should **not** be null

```
{
    "email":"test@test.test",
    "age":33,
    "disconnect":{
                  "text":"test",
                  "beginning":"test",
                  "end":"test"
                 }
}
```

I expect `detailUser.getDisconnect()==null` to be `true` but get `false` when `Disconnect` fields (text, beginning, end) are all `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that there is a `Disconnect` object in your json that has all its fields `null`. Gson is working as it should but if you want to have `Disconnect` to be `null` whenever its all fields are `null` you have some options.

One option  is to create custom `JsonDeserializer`, like:

```
public class NullAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<Disconnect> {
    @Override
    public Disconnect deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        Disconnect dc = new Gson().fromJson(json, typeOfT);
        // Here you decide the criteria in which case to return the Disconnect or null
        // I decided that if any of its fields is not null it is neither null
        if (dc.beginning != null || dc.text != null || dc.end != null) {
            return dc;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Test it by registering with `GsonBuilder()`:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    DetailUser du = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Disconnect.class, new NullAdapter())
            .create()
            .fromJson(**YOUR_NULL_JSON**, DetailUser.class);
    assertNull(du.disconnect);
}
```